# Python: calling method in the map function

Tags: python, methods, list-comprehension, map-function

`map()` and list comprehension are roughly equivalent:

```
map(function, list1)
[function(i) for i in list1]
```

What if the function we want to use is a method?

```
[i.function() for i in list1]
map(.function, list1) # error!
map(run_method(function), list1) # error!
```

How could I perform this kind of manipulation with `map`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You'd use [`operator.methodcaller()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller):

```
from operator import methodcaller

map(methodcaller('function'), list1)
```

`methodcaller()` accepts additional arguments that are then passed into the called method; `methodcaller('foo', 'bar', spam='eggs')(object)` is the equivalent of `object.foo('bar', spam='eggs')`.

If all objects in `list1` are the same type or subclasses of that type, *and* the method you want to call doesn't take any arguments, you can pass in the unbound method to `map` as the function to call. For example, to lowercase all strings in a list, you can use:

```
map(str.lower, list_of_strings)
```

where `str.lower` is the unbound method on the `str` type.

Note that a list comprehension is not really the equivalent of a `map()` here. `map()` can only do *one* loop, entirely in C. `map()` will `zip()` multiple iterable arguments, and `map()` in Python 3 is itself an iterator.

A list comprehension on the other hand can do multiple (nested) loops and add in filtering, and the left-hand expression can be any valid Python expression including nested list comprehensions.

Answer (score 1):

You could invoke the method directly using the type of the object.

```
map(lambda x: type(x).function(), list1)
```

which is not much more exciting than the more straightforward

```
map(lambda x: x.function(), list1)
```

However, it does point out that it would be nice if Python had a function composition operator, something like `f**g(x) == f(g(x))`. Then you could write

```
map(type**function, list1)
```

Comment: You are not actually calling the function; and using the `type()` call in a lambda is rather pointless as it just means your are mapping objects to dereference *just* the method.   It only becomes interesting if all objects in the list are the same type and you use a direct reference to the unbound method in the